# Show ProgressDialog on onLoadFinished of Loader

Tags: android, progressdialog, loader

My activity needs to show a list of file to the screen. So I used CursorLoader to load this data. I also have a ProgressDialog show in waiting time:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_video);

    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading data");
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.show();
 }
```

When onLoadFinished, I dismissed that progressDialog:

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mProgressDialog.show();

    if (mAdapter != null && data != null) {
        ArrayList<VideoRecord> mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        data.moveToFirst();

        while (!data.isAfterLast()) {......}
            data.moveToNext();
        }

        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(mArrayList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

But when the data change (ex: file renamed, file deleted), the loader reload. It reached onLoadFinished again.

I read the document:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html#onLoadFinished(android.content.Loader, D)

> Note that normally an application is not allowed to commit fragment transactions while in this call, since it can happen after an activity's state is saved. See FragmentManager.openTransaction() for further discussion on this.

mProgressDialog.show() onLoadFinished not show when data change. It is possible to show? Many thanks

Comment: You are showing and dismissing the dialog in the same process. onLoadFinished() first and last line. So this dialog is never been shown. Try to do it when you detect the data change, I mean, show the dialog.

Comment: Is there any listener to notify you when the data change?

Comment: @MiguelBenitez, Kise I try to show ProgressDialog when data change before, but it just show a dialog, the process icon inside doesn't spin :(

Comment: I had the same issue an It was caused because I was running the process to load data in the ui thread. Check how It's working your CursorLoader because It's supposed that It run in an asynctask

Comment: So if i want to spin my dialog, how can i do? Make loader not run in ui thread?